# Reuse Cmd+Tab for hammerspoon application switcher

Tags: macos, keyboard, window-manager, keybindings, application-switcher

I set up [hammerspoon](https://www.hammerspoon.org/) and use `hs.window.switcher` as mentioned [in the docs](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.switcher.html). I.e.

```
switcher_space = hs.window.switcher.new(hs.window.filter.new():setCurrentSpace(true):setDefaultFilter{})
hs.hotkey.bind('alt','tab',function()switcher_space:next()end)
hs.hotkey.bind('alt-shift','tab',function()switcher_space:previous()end)
```

This works fine with <kbd>alt</kbd>, however when I try to use <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead, the native application switcher is used.

How to reuse <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> or disable the standard application switcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use cmd+tab and shift+command+tab to switch windows, you need to use eventtap so that you can override the default app switcher hotkey. See code below. We set up a window `switcher` that switches between windows within the current space. `mapCmdTab` is a callback function for every time a key is pressed. If tab was pressed while only the cmd modifier was on, then we call `switcher:next()` to go to switch to the next window. Returning `true` means that the key press is not forwarded on to other applications (but it is if we return false or nil). If shift+command+tab was pressed, we go to the previous window. For some reason, the (capital?) tab character is `string.char(25)` when shift was being pressed.

```
switcher = hs.window.switcher.new(hs.window.filter.new():setCurrentSpace(true))
function mapCmdTab(event)
    local flags = event:getFlags()
    local chars = event:getCharacters()
    if chars == "\t" and flags:containExactly{'cmd'} then
        switcher:next()
        return true
    elseif chars == string.char(25) and flags:containExactly{'cmd','shift'} then
        switcher:previous()
        return true
    end
end
tapCmdTab = hs.eventtap.new({hs.eventtap.event.types.keyDown}, mapCmdTab)
tapCmdTab:start()
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation about what the code does?

Comment: I added some explanation.

Comment: For others coming here, to include minimized applications, add `:setDefaultFilter{}` as is done in the question.